# Access elements of memory bytes in solidity

Tags: solidity

I'm having trouble using bytes in solidity.
my code:

```
function get() public{
    string memory sl = "asddsa";
    bytes memory aa = bytes(sl);
    log("123");
    aa[0] = 2;
}
```

if I run this code, i will recieve no log. otherwise, if I delete the line "aa[0] = 2", i will recieve the log. 
I'm not sure what the problem is but it seems that there is a problem accessing elements of bytes.
Have anyone faced this kind of problems before? please help me solve it. thanks.
By the way, when I put that code into a Library, it runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not logging because your transaction is failing. The last line of your function (`aa[0] = 2;`) is attempting to set a value to an in memory dynamic array, which is not allowed. You need to either change `aa` to be a storage variable, or declare the size of the array like this:

```
function get() public{
    string memory sl = "asddsa";
    byte[] memory aa = new byte[](bytes(sl).length);
    log("123");
    aa[0] = 2;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. if i change memory to storage, it means I need gas to have the transaction done, right?

Comment: sorry, i'm just a new member, cannot up vote your comment.

Comment: by the way, if I have this function verify(bytes32 hash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s), how can I access each element in 'hash'? it seems to fail if I use hash[1].

Comment: 1) Everything requires gas (even view function calls). But, yes, storage operations do require more gas than most other operations. 2) If you can't upvote, you can still accept the answer if it resolves your issue. 3) You may need to post another question describing what you're actually trying to do. From the method signature, it looks like you're trying to run `ecrecover` on a message. You don't need to reference individual bytes for that. If you need to slice a bytes32, you can use `mstore` in assembly.